# How to determine the total running time when using the fminsearch in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

does anyone here got an idea what is the command that i should use in MATLAB to determine the total computer time taken to run the Nelder-Mead algorithm using FMINSEARCH until it stop. TQ

Answer (score 3):

First, you can check the computation time by using the [tic](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/tic.html)/[toc](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) instructions. For example:

```
tic
x = fminsearch('x^2+x+2',10)
toc
```

Second,the Nelder-Mead algorithm is an Unconstrained Nonlinear Optimization Algorithm that goes iteratively towards the minimum in a heuristic way. From my point of view, it could be slower and not finding a 'good' minima. Thus, I would suggest you to use Quasi-Newton methods, like BFGS. You just need to use the function [fminunc](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to time a specific piece of code, you can use

```
tic
% yourcode
toc
```

If you cannot edit the code or want to check the total runtime for a function, try

```
help profile
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
t=cputime; 
your_operation; 
cputime-t
```

returns computational (CPU) time which was spend by your processes. Tic/toc commands return elapsed running time; this may depend on other programmes, which are using the CPU at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18955502/8239061), the function [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) is preferred to using [`tic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) & [`toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) due to internal operations in `timeit` that account for MATLAB nuances.

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html),

> `timeit` calls the specified function multiple times, and computes the
> median of the measurements.

Consider the example taken from the documentation for [`fminsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html).

```
% MATLAB R2022a
fun = @(x)100*(x(2) - x(1)^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2;
x0 = [-1.2,1];
[x,fval] = fminsearch(fun,x0);

RunTime = timeit(@() fminsearch(fun,x0));      % median runtime in seconds
```