# Fast computation of a gradient of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, image-processing, gradient, sparse-matrix

I was trying to optimize my code and found that one of my code is a bottleneck. My code was :

```
function [] = one(x)
I = imread('coins.png');
I = double(I);
I = imresize(I,[x x]);
sig=.8;    % scale parameter in Gaussian kernel
G=fspecial('gaussian',15,sig); % Caussian kernel
Img_smooth=conv2(I,G,'same');  % smooth image by Gaussiin convolution
[Ix,Iy]=gradient(Img_smooth);
f=Ix.^2+Iy.^2;
g=1./(1+f);  % edge indicator function.
end
```

I tried to run it like this : 
clear all;close all;

```
x=4000;N=1;
tic
for i=1:N
    one(x);
end
toc
```

I found that the largest amount of time was consumed by the **gradient operator** statement(about 60%) of the total time. So it got me thinking how can I optimize my code further ....

I consulted few sites like : [Dgradient](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29887-dgradient) and http://regularize.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/how-fast-can-you-calculate-the-gradient-of-an-image-in-matlab/

However Dgradient is a MEX file and I do not want to use it. I wanted to write my own gradient function. I read in the blogs that the gradient operator in matlab is significantly slower and be speeded up by using shift & substract and sparse matrix.

I do not have knowledge about sparse matrix. However I did try doing it by using shift and substract method. However **I am preety sure my code is wrong**. Please could anyone clarify what kind of difference matlab uses for calculation of its gradient ? And show me how to do it in my code ?

```
clc;clear all;close all;
I = imread('coins.png');
I = double(I(:,:,1));
I = imresize(I,[4 4]);

tic
[dx dy] = gradient(I);
toc

tic
%//Doing forward difference on both directions
dx1 = [I(:,2:end) I(:,end)] - I;
dy1 = [I(2:end,:);I(end,:)] - I;
toc
```

Please could you guys look into the code and suggest me how to correctly apply it ? Or guide me how to do so using sparse matrix ?

Comment: have you tried just using `diff`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html

Comment: diff works with 1D array and I am working on an Image which is 2D or 3D. Please explain how diff is applicable in my case ?

Comment: `diff(I,1,2)` difference between columns, i.e. the same as your `dx1`. Please read the doc link I posted, diff does not only apply to 1D arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will go through it and let you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to all of your answers and helpful suggestions . I took the suggestions of **pseudoDust**,  **Hugues** , **Dima** and **High Performance Mark** and wrote my own code. My code is given below :

```
clc;clear all;close all;
x=32;
I = imread('coins.png');
I = imresize(I,[x x]);
I = double(I(:,:,1));

tic
[dx dy] = gradient(I);
toc

tic
[m,n]=size(I);
A = [I(:,2:end) zeros(m,1)];
B = [zeros(m,1) I(:,1:end-1)];
dx1 = [I(:,2)-I(:,1) (A(:,2:end-1)-B(:,2:end-1))./2 I(:,end)-I(:,end-1)];
A = [I(2:end,:) ; zeros(1,n)];
B = [zeros(1,n) ; I(1:end-1,:)];
dy1 = [I(2,:)-I(1,:) ; (A(2:end-1,:)-B(2:end-1,:))./2 ; I(end,:)-I(end-1,:)];
toc

nnz(dx-dx1)
nnz(dy-dy1)
```

**My basic idea was that** : Gradient averages the 2 adjacent positions (left and right or top and bottom), except for the edges where it takes the difference between the value and the adjacent position. I then checked the matrix generated by me (dx1,dy1) with the matrix generated by matlab gradient function (dx,dy).

```
Elapsed time is 0.010232 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000066 seconds.
ans =
     0
ans =
     0
```

So I believe my code is correct. Also the timing results was surprising to say the least. I then timed my code with the matlab one for different sizes of the images.

I got this results :

---

```
%x=16
Elapsed time is 0.010790 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000057 seconds.
%x=32
Elapsed time is 0.010564 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000069 seconds.
%x=64
Elapsed time is 0.010627 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000152 seconds.
%x=128
Elapsed time is 0.011346 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000669 seconds.
%x=256
Elapsed time is 0.017311 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004468 seconds.
%x=512
Elapsed time is 0.044148 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.030435 seconds.
%x=1024
Elapsed time is 0.093386 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.093029 seconds.
%x=2048
Elapsed time is 0.345423 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.387762 seconds.
```

---

So my conclusion was this : For image size upto 1024X1024 my code was faster than the gradient command inbuilt in matlab.

Edit : I updated my answer and added this graph:

**It clearly shows** that for smaller array size my code is significantly faster than the matlab gradient function.

[image]

**Is my code correct ?** Guys please look through it and check. Do give your feedback. I am literally a novice in matlab and am highly surprised by this result. Please check whether what I am doing is correct or not ?

Answer (score 2):

```
dx1 = (I(:,[1:end end]) - I(:,[1 1:end]));
dx1(:,2:(end-1))=dx1(:,2:(end-1))*0.5;
dy1 = (I([1:end end],:) - I([1 1:end],:));
dy1(2:(end-1),:)=dy1(2:(end-1),:)*0.5;
```

Should work, gradient averages the 2 adjacent positions (left and right or top and bottom), except for the edges where it takes the difference between the value and the adjacent position.

Comment: I am trying to write a gradient function which does exactly as the gradient command in matlab does but significantly faster. That is why I am trying it. Your command gives some other values.

Comment: Hi again could you look into your code again. I tried it but the answer is not coming correct. Please check and let me know

Answer (score 1):

It is nice that you want to write your own gradient function, and as mentioned in the blogs, some methods are better than others. However the blog entry compares nested for-loops to shift and subtract and sparse matrix; nowhere does it say that `gradient` is slow or un-optimized. Usualy Matlab functions are implemented in C++ and make use of BLAS and LAPACK libraries. They should beat any of the techniques that you suggest, but go ahead and please check that out for us :-)

Regarding your code, I doubt that you want to resize your image to [4 4]!
Otherwise your code is correct.

You have implicitly used a Robert operator for your gradient ( `dI/dx = I(x+1) - I(x)` )

The `gradient` function uses central differences, `[- 1 0 1]` in the x-direction.

The numerical results for each operators will be a bit different.

Note that in Matlab R2013a, the `imgradient` function uses a Sobel operator, `[1 0 -1; 2 0 -2;1 0 -1]` in the x-direction.

Consider taking a look at [imgradient](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/imgradient.html)

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me what is the difference between the normal gradient command and imgradient command ?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html and http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/imgradient.html . Basically you don't have any option in the basic one. The im version lets you choose your kernel, whether to use GPU, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I read the documentation. Unfortunately its only available in R2013 and I am using R2012. But can you tell me do they both give the same answer if I use the default case in the imgradient command ? As I dont have Matlab 2013A i am not being able to check .

Comment: No the answer will be different, I did write that. Do you have image processing toolbox? Then you can use `imfilter` with the Sobel operator and compare.

Comment: I am really sorry for my ignorance but I have a few queries that are still not clear to me . I first used only the gradient operator to calculate dx. Then I used imfilter alongwith the sobel filter to calculate dx1. Both are not at all same. Can you please tell me why this is not so ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You're right, I have mixed a bit 2012/2013. My answer is updated (try central differences). I don't have Matlab installed here, but the answer to those details is in the code!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of Matlab (R2012b and up, IIRC) and the Image Processing Toolbox, then you can use the [imgradient](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html) function.

Comment: imgradient is not available in 2012a

Comment: True. But 2013a just came out.

Comment: @roni, well, that's how life is. If you don't have a more recent version, then you should use `imfilter` and `fspecial` to compute your gradients. So it's not so bad. :)