# How can I (efficiently) compute a moving average of a vector?

Tags: matlab, moving-average

I've got a vector and I want to calculate the moving average of it (using a window of width 5).

For instance, if the vector in question is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, then

- the first entry of the resulting vector should be the sum of all entries in `[1,2,3,4,5]` (i.e. `15`);
- the second entry of the resulting vector should be the sum of all entries in `[2,3,4,5,6]` (i.e. `20`);
- etc.

In the end, the resulting vector should be `[15,20,25,30]`. How can I do that?

Comment: See the [`conv` function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`conv`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) function is right up your alley:

```
>> x = 1:8;
>> y = conv(x, ones(1,5), 'valid')

y =
    15    20    25    30
```

## Benchmark

Three answers, three different methods... Here is a quick benchmark (different input sizes, fixed window width of 5) using [`timeit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html); feel free to poke holes in it (in the comments) if you think it needs to be refined.

`conv` emerges as the fastest approach; it's about twice as fast as [coin's approach (using `filter`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26982654/2541573), and about four times as fast as [Luis Mendo's approach (using `cumsum`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26984386/2541573).

[image]

Here is another benchmark (fixed input size of `1e4`, different window widths). Here, [Luis Mendo's `cumsum` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26984386/2541573) emerges as the clear winner, because its complexity is primarily governed by the length of the input and is insensitive to the width of the window.

[image]

## Conclusion

To summarize, you should

- use the `conv` approach if your window is relatively small,
- use the `cumsum` approach if your window is relatively large.

## Code (for benchmarks)

```matlab
function benchmark

    clear all
    w = 5;                 % moving average window width
    u = ones(1, w); 
    n = logspace(2,6,60);  % vector of input sizes for benchmark
    t1 = zeros(size(n));   % preallocation of time vectors before the loop
    t2 = t1;
    th = t1;

    for k = 1 : numel(n)

        x = rand(1, round(n(k)));  % generate random row vector

        % Luis Mendo's approach (cumsum)
        f = @() luisMendo(w, x);
        tf(k) = timeit(f);

        % coin's approach (filter)
        g = @() coin(w, u, x);
        tg(k) = timeit(g);

        % Jubobs's approach (conv)
        h = @() jubobs(u, x);
        th(k) = timeit(h);
    end

    figure
    hold on
    plot(n, tf, 'bo')
    plot(n, tg, 'ro')
    plot(n, th, 'mo')
    hold off
    xlabel('input size')
    ylabel('time (s)')
    legend('cumsum', 'filter', 'conv')

end

function y = luisMendo(w,x)
    cs = cumsum(x);
    y(1,numel(x)-w+1) = 0; %// hackish way to preallocate result
    y(1) = cs(w);
    y(2:end) = cs(w+1:end) - cs(1:end-w);
end

function y = coin(w,u,x)
    y = filter(u, 1, x);
    y = y(w:end);
end

function jubobs(u,x)
    y = conv(x, u, 'valid');
end
```

---

```
function benchmark2

    clear all
    w = round(logspace(1,3,31));    % moving average window width 
    n = 1e4;  % vector of input sizes for benchmark
    t1 = zeros(size(n));   % preallocation of time vectors before the loop
    t2 = t1;
    th = t1;

    for k = 1 : numel(w)
        u = ones(1, w(k));
        x = rand(1, n);  % generate random row vector

        % Luis Mendo's approach (cumsum)
        f = @() luisMendo(w(k), x);
        tf(k) = timeit(f);

        % coin's approach (filter)
        g = @() coin(w(k), u, x);
        tg(k) = timeit(g);

        % Jubobs's approach (conv)
        h = @() jubobs(u, x);
        th(k) = timeit(h);
    end

    figure
    hold on
    plot(w, tf, 'bo')
    plot(w, tg, 'ro')
    plot(w, th, 'mo')
    hold off
    xlabel('window size')
    ylabel('time (s)')
    legend('cumsum', 'filter', 'conv')

end

function y = luisMendo(w,x)
    cs = cumsum(x);
    y(1,numel(x)-w+1) = 0; %// hackish way to preallocate result
    y(1) = cs(w);
    y(2:end) = cs(w+1:end) - cs(1:end-w);
end

function y = coin(w,u,x)
    y = filter(u, 1, x);
    y = y(w:end);
end

function jubobs(u,x)
    y = conv(x, u, 'valid');
end
```

Comment: Taking a look with R2016b: the story is pretty much the same. However, R2016a introduced the [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) builtin. For the small window size case its performance is roughly on par with the `filter` approach ([though slightly noisy](http://i.imgur.com/GEeQWMI.png)). For the large window size case its performance is on par with `cumsum`.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html). This approach probably requires fewer operations than `conv` does:

```
x = 1:8
n = 5;
cs = cumsum(x);
result = cs(n:end) - [0 cs(1:end-n)];
```

To save a little time, you can replace the last line by

```
%// clear result
result(1,numel(x)-n+1) = 0; %// hackish way to preallocate result
result(1) = cs(n);
result(2:end) = cs(n+1:end) - cs(1:end-n);
```

Comment: @Jubobs Why `u = ones(1, 6)`? Shouldn't it be `u = ones(1, w)`? Your three computations of `y` should give the same size. Also, for reliable timing use `timeit`

Comment: @Jubobs If you update your benchmarking (BTW +1 already for the effort), could you use my second version?

Comment: Yes, that `6` is a typo; I'm not sure how it got there. I'll rerun the benchmark later. I don't have access to MATLAB right now, but I'll do that (with `timit`) when I get the chance.

Comment: @Jubobs I see. The advantage of `cumsum` is only apparent for larger values of `w`. For example, for `w=50` it is indeed the fastest method (on my machine). Good benchmarking job!

Comment: Interesting. I'll rerun the benchmark, but I'll make the window width vary. Thanks for telling me about `timeit`; I had been using `tic`/`toc` all along.

Comment: @Jubobs So did I until recently; but `timeit` [does a better job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952552/timing-code-in-matlab) at timing

Comment: @Jubobs Interesting results! It makes sense that the `cumsum` approach is  insensitive to window size. It does approximately `n` sums and `n` subtractions, no matter what the window size is (in fact, that savings in computations is what led me to think it could be an interesting approach)

Comment: Yes, now that you've spelled it out to me, it all makes sense. Great! The overall conclusion is that you're better off using `cumsum` if your window is large, but you should use `conv` if your window is narrow.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, that sums it up very well

Comment: @LuisMendo I used this [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100405/31516)! :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Hehe, well done! This reminds me that my submission to that challenge is also safe now...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve the size of your input vector, I suggest using `filter`

```
>> x = 1:8;
>> y = filter(ones(1,5), 1, x)

y =
     1     3     6    10    15    20    25     30

>> y = (5:end)

y =
     15    20    25    30
```

Comment: Note that you're using `filter` incorrectly. The syntax is `filter(b,a,x)`, so you should use `filter(ones(1,5), 1, x)`, instead. You should also discard the first 4 elements of the result afterwards.