# Average on contiguos segments of a vector

Tags: matlab, filter, moving-average

I'm sure this is a trivial question for a signals person. I need to find the function in Matlab that outputs averaging of contiguous segments of windowsize= l of a vector, e.g.

```
origSignal: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
windowSize = 3;
output = [2 5 8]; % i.e. [(1+2+3)/3 (4+5+6)/3 (7+8+9)/3]
```

EDIT: Neither one of the options presented in [How can I (efficiently) compute a moving average of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981478/how-can-i-efficiently-compute-a-moving-average-of-a-vector) seems to work because I need that the window of size 3 slides, and doesnt include any of the previous elements... Maybe I'm missing it. Take a look at my example...

Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question. It seems related somehow, but it doesn't do what I need.

Comment: not good: x = 1:9; y = conv(x, ones(1,3), 'valid')/3; y =

     2     3     4     5     6     7     8

Comment: I edited the title because you are not lookign for a moving average. A moving average is an average at each point of the data, considering a N-window

Comment: Will originalSignal size be a multiple of widow size, always?

Comment: Then [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your signal and use [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html), e.g. `mean(reshape(origSignal, windowSize, []))`

Comment: Ander, thanks.. No, not necessarily. The vector is a time signal, 4 minutes sampling, so the original signal can to be trimmed at the end...

Comment: @OliverAmundsen Then you would need to explain what to do in that case.... Because your example doesnt hold. What happens when `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]`

Comment: right, just remove the 7 and the 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of the original data is always a multiple of widowsize:

```
mean(reshape(origSignal,windowSize,[]));
```

Else, in one line:

```
mean(reshape(origSignal(1:end-mod(length(origSignal),windowSize)),windowSize,[]))
```

This is the same as before, but the signal is only taken to the end minus the extra values less than windowsize.