# fPerformance of outer product in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, architecture, product, allocation

I have two vectors, say A:1xN and B:1xM. I want to compute their outer product and add the result to a NxM matrix. Now, I split this into two parts, first computing (A')B and then adding it. On profiling, the first step takes way more time than the adding (8x). Since the number of multiplications in the first step is the same as the number of additions in the second step, is the difference only due to my architecture supporting faster additions? Or is it the time taken to allocate the memory for storing the result in the first step?

```
>> x = randn(1,10000);
>> y = randn(1,10000);
>> tic; z=x'*y; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.560743 seconds.
>> tic; z=z+z; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.132228 seconds.
>> tic; z=z.*z; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.124191 seconds.
```

So I figured that it is not a mult vs addition. z = z+z and z = z.*z have similar times.

Comment: Show your codes and explain the timings w.r.t them?

Comment: Multiplying floating-point values takes more time than adding them. The behaviour you see may be normal

Comment: Well, in the edit, doesnt seem to be the case. It could be in some architectures, not here though.

Comment: So what's the question exactly?

Comment: Well, the outer product should technically be the same number of multiplications as z=z.*z, but it is slower by a significant factor. I dont understand why.

Comment: @user3287648 I can't test this in MATLAB right now, but memory allocation may play a part in this discrepancy. Try initialising `z` to a matrix of zeroes before running `z=x'*y`; and see if the running times remain the same. Also, `tic`/`toc` is not a reliable way of profiling code. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18955502/2541573

Comment: I tried pre allocating z as well, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things different between using two matrices and the outer product. If you think of your own "C" implementation and compare them it would become obvious.

1. The outer product might need multiple indices to keep track of where you are reading from vectors and where you are writing to in the matrix. i.e. more loop overhead.
2. If you are adding or multiplying with the same matrix you only need a single index for the loop.
3. Second and third operations are also in-place operations needing less memory pointers.

Comment: I agree about the two indices, but that cannot add so much overhead. I dont get the third point. Arent the reads and writes the same?

Comment: There are less number of address pointers. I updated the sentence. You are right that number of writes are same. But number of reads are more in the first one since it is reading two variables.

Comment: Though it is reading two variables, total reads need not be more. They would infact be less than say z = A.* B wjere A and B are full matrices of the same dimension as result of the outer product.