# Anonymous Functions Dont Work inside parfor loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, anonymous-function

I'm not sure if I found a matlab bug or am doing something wrong,  but it seems that calling anonymous functions inside a parfor loop will significantly slow it down (even slower than serial performance)

Is this correct?

See this code:

```
tic; parfor i=1:6, min(randn(10000000,1)); end; toc
tic; for i=1:6, min(randn(10000000,1)); end; toc
```

Parallel Elapsed time is 0.510345 seconds.

Serial Elapsed time is 0.932137 seconds.

Same thing except using anon function:

```
q = @(x) min(randn(10000000,1));
tic; parfor i=1:6, q([]); end; toc   %parelel
tic; for i=1:6, q([]); end; toc     %serial
```

Parallel Elapsed time is 4.208346 seconds.

Serial Elapsed time is 0.933594 seconds.

Comment: Interesting.... I'm curious to know why this is the case too.

Comment: Could you verify the `0.510345`? I get roughly the same timings, but there i get 3s. What version of matlab are you using?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am using 2014b

Comment: I got the roughly the same results in first and second cases. 2012a

Comment: In 2013a on my machine, the running time is 0.67 - 0.70 seconds for all four commands. There may be a bit of initialization overhead distorting the results of the first run. Try repeating the test like this: `q = @(x) min(randn(10000000,1)); tic; parfor i=1:6, q([]); end; toc; tic; for i=1:6, q([]); end; toc; tic; parfor i=1:6, q([]); end; toc; tic; for i=1:6, q([]); end; toc;`

Comment: On my machine I can only reproduce this on the first run. Matlab and `tic` and `toc` need some warming up. If you want more accurate measurements use `timeit`. See: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18955502/3139711).