# MATLAB: datetime and etime

Tags: matlab

I need to use `etime` to calculate how many seconds a computation takes. I thought about something like this:

```
t1 = datetime('now');

% Do some computation
t2 = datetime('now');
temp = etime(t2, t1)
```

But I am getting this  error message:

> Error using etime(line 40), Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The inputs to `etime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/etime.html#inputarg_t2t1) are expected to be vectors that are the same format as the output of [`clock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html) and *not* `datetime` objects.

```
t1 = clock;
t2 = clock;
elapsed = etime(t2, t1)
```

It is likely easier to surround your code with [`tic`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) and [`toc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) which will automatically compute the elapsed time.

```
tmr = tic;
% do stuff
elapsed = toc(tmr);
```

That being said, if you want an accurate measurement of execution time, it is [far better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952552/timing-code-in-matlab) to use [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html).