# matlab efficiency - slicing vs assignment

Tags: matlab

I am curious, is there a large speed difference in MATLAB between computing with a slicing of a matrix vs. assigning the slicing to another variable, then computing with the variable?

I.e. the difference between the following:

```
A = randn(1000,1000);
x = randn(500,1);
y = A(:,1:500)*x;
```

and

```
A = randn(1000,1000);
x = randn(500,1);

Ahat = A(:,1:500);
y = Ahat*x;
```

I usually use the second for clarity, but is the latter more inefficient memory / computation wise because extra memory is being used in creating Ahat?

And does the answer change if I have to multiple by many x_i vectors? In that case, is it better to reassign to a new variable because (possibly) memory access for slicing is slower?

Comment: [Profile it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/code-performance.html) and find out...

Comment: For the suggestions to profile it, I will definitely do that, but I was wondering if there are any "theoretical justifications" for why one might be faster than the other. I guess what I'm really asking is: when I do A(:,1:500)*x, does MATLAB under the hood allocate another matrix for me, then multiply it by x, or does it do the multiplication using the original memory locations of A.

Comment: You can use `tic` and `toc` functions to time execution - results would probably depend quite a lot on which Matlab version you use. You should also do these calculations repeatedly within a for loop, to decrease random execution time bias.

Comment: @nirvana-msu `timeit` is far better than `tic` and `toc`

Comment: Profiling your code will also show you memory allocation, or you can monitor it at the OS level. There is no canonical answer because only The MathWorks has access to MATLAB's source code and the engine evolves over time.

Comment: @Suever could you please explain why is `timeit` better that `tic`/`toc`? Could not find any obvious reason with a quick search.

Comment: @nirvana-msu For precisely the reasons that you brought up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952552/timing-code-in-matlab

Comment: @excaza I see, then I guess profiling it per your suggestion is the best way to investigate this and there is no general one size fits all rule. If you post your answer I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Comment: In my brief testing they are statistically indistinguishable.