# Does MATLAB evaluate code with different speed when reading from file, evalc(), and from console?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the same MATLAB code, I have the following 3 ways to run them

1) put the code into a code.m, then run('code.m')
2) evalc(code)
3) paste the code into the MATLAB console, then type 'return'

Do they run in the same speed? I profile a bit, and found their speed are almost the same, and for some reason, the first approach is slightly faster. I am not sure if my code is large enough to draw any conclusion.

Comment: Use `timeit` to test the execution time.

Comment: @Suever How is timeit different from tic;toc?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18955502/670206)